# standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, centos

standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "permission denied" error is displayed in the logs when I try to run the containers as a non-root user. That's all that is displayed. found nothing significant with --verbose option. No clue found with strace.

Same container runs fine if I run it as a root user (by specifying root: user in docker-compose). I know issue is not because of anything in the docker-compose file or the volumes. "docker run imagename" also returns exact same issue. Same Image runs perfectly if I build it again by removing "USER appuser".

Sample Dockerfile to replicate same issue. It works fine until i remove comment from "USER appuser". When I rebuild with "USER appuser" it gives me the exact same issue.

```
FROM dev.registry.ews.int/ews-cm/centos-7-minimal:latest   
RUN  yum -y install shadow-utils   
RUN groupadd -r -g 20163 appuser \   
    && useradd -r -m -u 20163 -g 20163 appuser   
USER appuser   
CMD ["echo","Hello"]
```

/var/lib/docker is mounted with exec permission. We checked and seems Selinux is also not causing this problem. I tried everything I could find on Internet but nothing helped so far. Appreciate if someone can provide any pointers.

This is how my ID appuser looks like on host machine
    uid=20163(appuser) gid=20163(appuser) groups=20163(appuser),992(docker)
    appuser id and group are available in /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid files.
Even id is same in the image and on the host machine which is 20163.

This is how my mount looks:
    /dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_docker on /var/lib/docker type ext4 
    (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)

```
docker-ce info:
Name        : docker-ce  
Arch        : x86_64  
Epoch       : 3  
Version     : 19.03.5  
Release     : 3.el7  

It works fine when I use docker 1.13.1 but I can not use it since its very old and has lot of vulnerabilities.
Name        : docker  
Arch        : x86_64  
Epoch       : 2  
Version     : 1.13.1  
Release     : 109.gitcccb291.el7.centos  

OS Information:  
NAME="CentOS Linux"  
VERSION="7 (Core)"  
ID="centos"  
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"  
VERSION_ID="7"  
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"  
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
```